# Unable to executive function of smart contract on android studio java file

Tags: web3j, java

I am trying to execute some functions of my deployed contract in Android Studio through a Java file. I have generated Java Wrapper files. However, when I run Android Studio, there is no data added to the smart contract. Is there anything wrong with my codes? Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my Java Code :

```
package smth.ui.home;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import org.web3j.crypto.Credentials;
import org.web3j.protocol.Web3j;
import org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.TransactionReceipt;
import org.web3j.protocol.http.HttpService;
import org.web3j.tx.ManagedTransaction;

import smth.R;
import smth.pojo.UserAccountFactory;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });

        Web3j web3 = Web3j.build(new HttpService("https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x7b8418fc1d6d82e221a3ec4519c2a1c0de04a4a5a4c421e2e45ec63c3109737e"));

        Credentials credentials1 = Credentials.create("privateKey");
        try {
            UserAccountFactory contract = UserAccountFactory.load("0x1db931d46dc846bd2e7ff0f33d9eb43fc62e6981", web3, credentials1, ManagedTransaction.GAS_PRICE, UserAccountFactory.GAS_LIMIT);
            TransactionReceipt transactionReceipt = contract.registerNewUser("wl1@gmail.com", "Hi1231","Customer").sendAsync().get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        web3.shutdown();

        return root;
    }
}
```

And here is my JavaWrapper code :

```
package smth.pojo;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import org.web3j.abi.TypeReference;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Function;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Type;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Utf8String;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Bytes32;
import org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256;
import org.web3j.crypto.Credentials;
import org.web3j.protocol.Web3j;
import org.web3j.protocol.core.RemoteCall;
import org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.TransactionReceipt;
import org.web3j.tuples.generated.Tuple4;
import org.web3j.tx.Contract;
import org.web3j.tx.TransactionManager;

/**
 * <p>Auto generated code.
 * <p><strong>Do not modify!</strong>
 * <p>Please use the <a href="https://docs.web3j.io/command_line.html">web3j command line tools</a>,
 * or the org.web3j.codegen.SolidityFunctionWrapperGenerator in the 
 * <a href="https://github.com/web3j/web3j/tree/master/codegen">codegen module</a> to update.
 *
 * <p>Generated with web3j version 3.3.1.
 */
public class UserAccountFactory extends Contract {
    private static final String BINARY = null;

    protected static final HashMap<String, String> _addresses;

    static {
        _addresses = new HashMap<>();
    }

    protected UserAccountFactory(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        super(BINARY, contractAddress, web3j, credentials, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    protected UserAccountFactory(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        super(BINARY, contractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    public static RemoteCall<UserAccountFactory> deploy(Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return deployRemoteCall(UserAccountFactory.class, web3j, credentials, gasPrice, gasLimit, BINARY, "");
    }

    public static RemoteCall<UserAccountFactory> deploy(Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return deployRemoteCall(UserAccountFactory.class, web3j, transactionManager, gasPrice, gasLimit, BINARY, "");
    }

    public RemoteCall<TransactionReceipt> editUserDetails(BigInteger _userNo, String _oldPassword, String _newPassword) {
        final Function function = new Function(
                "editUserDetails", 
                Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(_userNo), 
                new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Utf8String(_oldPassword), 
                new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Utf8String(_newPassword)), 
                Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
        return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
    }

    public RemoteCall<TransactionReceipt> loginUser(BigInteger _userNo, String _password) {
        final Function function = new Function(
                "loginUser", 
                Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(_userNo), 
                new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Utf8String(_password)), 
                Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
        return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
    }

    public RemoteCall<TransactionReceipt> registerNewUser(String _email, String _password, String _accountType) {
        final Function function = new Function(
                "registerNewUser", 
                Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Utf8String(_email), 
                new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Utf8String(_password), 
                new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Utf8String(_accountType)), 
                Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());
        return executeRemoteCallTransaction(function);
    }

    public RemoteCall<BigInteger> userCount() {
        final Function function = new Function("userCount", 
                Arrays.<Type>asList(), 
                Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}));
        return executeRemoteCallSingleValueReturn(function, BigInteger.class);
    }

    public RemoteCall<Tuple4<BigInteger, String, byte[], String>> userList(BigInteger param0) {
        final Function function = new Function("userList", 
                Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(param0)), 
                Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}, new TypeReference<Utf8String>() {}, new TypeReference<Bytes32>() {}, new TypeReference<Utf8String>() {}));
        return new RemoteCall<Tuple4<BigInteger, String, byte[], String>>(
                new Callable<Tuple4<BigInteger, String, byte[], String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Tuple4<BigInteger, String, byte[], String> call() throws Exception {
                        List<Type> results = executeCallMultipleValueReturn(function);
                        return new Tuple4<BigInteger, String, byte[], String>(
                                (BigInteger) results.get(0).getValue(), 
                                (String) results.get(1).getValue(), 
                                (byte[]) results.get(2).getValue(), 
                                (String) results.get(3).getValue());
                    }
                });
    }

    public static UserAccountFactory load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return new UserAccountFactory(contractAddress, web3j, credentials, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    public static UserAccountFactory load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return new UserAccountFactory(contractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    protected String getStaticDeployedAddress(String networkId) {
        return _addresses.get(networkId);
    }

    public static String getPreviouslyDeployedAddress(String networkId) {
        return _addresses.get(networkId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have the HTTP service endpoint wrong.

If I check that [link](http://%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Web3j%20web3%20=%20Web3j.build(new%20HttpService(%22https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x7b8418fc1d6d82e221a3ec4519c2a1c0de04a4a5a4c421e2e45ec63c3109737e%22));), it looks like it refers to a certain transaction.

However, when you create a `web3j` instance, you should specify a node endpoint. You can get one using the [infura](https://infura.io/) API, or you need to set up an Ethereum client (Geth for example) connecting to the `Ropsten` network and put its address when creating the `web3j` instance.

You can refer to [docs](http://docs.web3j.io/) for more information.

Also, `sendAsync().get()` is same as calling `send()`.